# How to set default value for new objects only, in Rails Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I know how to set default value for a column in rails, but i often find myself in situation like this, for example :
a boolean field named 'settled', its default value is false
all new objects will not be Settled until i say so, but i need all the old objects to be Settled

what i always do is making a rake task to toggle all the old objects, is there a way to do this in the migration but not as script, but to set a value to be default for old objects but not for the future schema

Comment: I meant something like the `default` here, `change_column_null(table_name, column_name, null, default = nil)`, it  replace existing +NULL+s with some other value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in your migration:

```
add_column :users, :is_banned, :bool
User.update_all(is_banned: false)
```